# minimum amount of prior to get a mixed-model to converge (in R)

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, hierarchical-bayesian

This may be a simple/naive question, but I have a non-converging `lmer()` model due to singularity of its random covariance matrix.

I was wondering what is a possible minimum prior specification in `blmer()` to get this singular model to converge?

```
library(lme4)
library(blme)  

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

m1 <- lmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = hsb)

m2 <- blmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses | sch.id), data = hsb, cov.prior = ???) ## A possible covariance prior
```

Comment: Is this the same data as before? If so then I thought we had established that random slopes over schools for a variable that is constant within schools doesnt make sense.

Comment: @RobertLong, no Rob, this is a completely different (and real) dataset. Here `ses` is a level-1 predictor. `sector` is a level-2 predictor.

Comment: @RobertLong, can you please check [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/490302/140365) out?

Comment: OK there is something a bit strange with your data, which may have something to do with the problem. if you convert `sch.id` to factor and fit an `lm` model with `sch.id` as a fixed effect, the model matrix is singular. I would fix this problem first.

Comment: @RobertLong, good catch! But I see no change after turning `sch.id` into a factor.

Comment: You have to fit `lm(math ~ ses*sector + sch.id, data = hsb) %>% summary()` with `schi.id` as a factor to see the problem.

Comment: @RobertLong, OR you mean here we have collinearity issue?

Comment: Maybe yes, or maybe some combinations of the factors don't exist. I don't know what the exact problem is, but you need to fix that singular model matrix for fixed effects, becuase that is basically what is used when you fit random slopes for the fixed effects, so that might be the cause of the singular VCV of random  effects. So once you can fit the `lm()` model with `sch.id` as a fixed effect you can move on to the mixed model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that, even once you convert `sch.id` into a factor variable:

```
library(dplyr)
hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
hsb <- hsb %>% mutate(sch.id=as.factor(sch.id))
```

and check that the `lm` model that Robert suggested actually runs (it does!), a slight simplification of the model (remove the interaction between ses and sector) leads to full convergence.

```
m0 <- lmer(math ~ ses + sector + (ses | sch.id), data = hsb)
summary(m0)

REML criterion at convergence: 46601.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1373 -0.7296  0.0225  0.7568  2.8920 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 sch.id   (Intercept)  3.9646  1.991        
          ses          0.4343  0.659    0.55
 Residual             36.8008  6.066        
Number of obs: 7185, groups:  sch.id, 160

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  11.4729     0.2315  49.568
ses           2.3854     0.1179  20.238
sector        2.5408     0.3445   7.375

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
       (Intr) ses   
ses     0.228       
sector -0.655 -0.079
```

The random effects variance term for ses is not particularly large and the ses variable itself is uncentered (its original metric). Once you add the `sector*ses` interaction, the random slope variance decreases to 0.08...so according to this model the interaction reduces the slope variance to nearly 0.

In multilevel models you are often better to consider centering level 1 variables about their group mean when estimating a random slope:

```
hsb <- hsb %>% group_by(sch.id) %>% mutate(smn_ses = mean(ses)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(cwc_ses=ses-smn_ses)
```

Then re-running your models. Below I show results from a `cwc_ses` model without the interaction and then from a model with the interaction. The interaction model no longer has convergence issues:

```
=============================================================
                                 Model 1        Model 2      
-------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)                          11.11 ***      11.39 ***
                                     (0.29)         (0.29)   
cwc_ses                               2.21 ***       2.80 ***
                                     (0.13)         (0.15)   
sector                                3.46 ***       2.81 ***
                                     (0.42)         (0.44)   
cwc_ses:sector                                      -1.34 ***
                                                    (0.23)   
-------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                               46681.31       46654.60    
BIC                               46729.47       46709.64    
Log Likelihood                   -23333.66      -23319.30    
Num. obs.                          7185           7185       
Num. groups: sch.id                 160            160       
Var: sch.id (Intercept)               6.84           6.74    
Var: sch.id cwc_ses                   0.70           0.27    
Cov: sch.id (Intercept) cwc_ses       1.27           1.05    
Var: Residual                        36.71          36.71    
=============================================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

The nice thing about centering in this way is that the `cwc_ses` coefficient is unambiguously a within-school comparison between students who differ on ses by 1 unit. And the random slope indicates how much between school variation there is in this within-school relationship. When you leave `ses` uncentered, you have a funky variable that contains information both about the within- and between-school association between ses and math achievement. A very useful reading on this topic is the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6274186_Centering_Predictor_Variables_in_Cross-Sectional_Multilevel_Models_A_New_Look_at_An_Old_Issue) by Enders and Tofighi from 2007.